# Entity Framework returning distinct records issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, distinct, complextype

I have a PC Enity which have some Properties , I would like to return a list of distinct Object (PC or Complex Type or whatever ) based on a property in order to bind it to server controls like DropDownList . And Because my method located in BLL I can't return anonymous type , So I created a Branch ComplexType which has two peroperties.

I wrote like this but it have repeative records:

```
List<Branch> result = ( from p in _context.PCs
                        where p.UserId== userId
                        select new Branch()
                                   {
                                      BranchId= p.BranchId,
                                      BranchName=p.BranchName
                                   }).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Edit :** 
Thank you all , This worked :

```
List<PC> result = _context.PCs
                  .GroupBy(p=>p.BranchName , p.BranchId})
                  .select(g=>g.First())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have two elements in the `result` list which are equal in both `BranchId` AND `BranchName`? This would be surprising because that should not happen with your example.

Comment: Do you use SQL Server? If yes, which version? If no, which database?

Comment: @Slauma :Yes . SQL Server 2008

Comment: That's strange. I have just tested your query and it works for me, see my answer below. Anyway, you have already another working solution...

Comment: By the way: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: EF 4.1 and Database first approach .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this will return distinct rows for all the columns in the select statement. If you want distinct rows for a particular column just specify that particular column

```
List<Branch> result = ( from p in _context.PCs
                        where p.UserId== userId
                        select new Branch()
                                   {
                                      BranchId= p.BranchId,
                                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want to get distinct values based on multiple columns, then you have to create a group and then pick first value from that group. In that case you will not use Distinct, for example

```
List<Branch> distinctResult = _context.PCs
  .GroupBy(p => new Branch {p.BranchId, p.BranchName} )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks . The first Code didn't worked, It return repeative records as well as I need branchName .

Comment: @Mostafa, replace BranchId, with BranchName in first statemet

Comment: The second didn't worked either . It get compile time error : Cannot convert Source type System.Collection.Generic.List<...Pc> to target type System.Collection.Generic.List<...Branch>

Comment: @Habit.osu :I try it too , But it have repeative records too

Comment: @Mostafa, just edit the second statement, forgot to specify Branch in select new statement, try it now

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce the problem (tested with SQL Server 2008 R2 and EF 4.1/DbContext). The query in your question...

```
List<Branch> result = ( from p in _context.PCs
                        where p.UserId== userId
                        select new Branch()
                        {
                            BranchId = p.BranchId,
                            BranchName = p.BranchName
                        })
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

... generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1],
[Distinct1].[BranchId] AS [BranchId],
[Distinct1].[BranchName] AS [BranchName]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
       [Extent1].[BranchId] AS [BranchId], 
       [Extent1].[BranchName] AS [BranchName], 
       1 AS [C1]
       FROM [dbo].[PCs] AS [Extent1]
) AS [Distinct1]
```

It is a DISTINCT on both columns and I get the expected distinct result - no duplicates in `BranchId` and `BranchName`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort , Maybe that's because the Key of PC Entity which is PCId and not BranchId

Answer (score 2):

You get duplicates because [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456.aspx) is unable to recognize two of your complex Branch objects as identical from their properties. It will just compare for object equality, which will return false (because you create two different objects, but with the same values).

You can use [Distinct(IQueryable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356803.aspx) to provide your own Comparer or implement the [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) Interface.

Comment: The example in the question is LINQ to Entities (`Distinct` of `IQueryable<T>`), not LINQ to Objects (`Distinct` of `IEnumerable<T>`). The object equality comparison does not apply in this case.

Comment: You are right, good call. Wrong Distinct() here. But wouldn't [providing an IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356803.aspx) still fix his problem?

Comment: No, because the overload of `Distinct` which takes the `IEqualityComparer` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. I'm actually very confused why the example in the question does not work. I'm going to test it...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

**1.**

```
class RolBaseComparer:IEqualityComparer<RolBase>
{
    public RolBaseComparer()
    {

    }

    public bool Equals(RolBase x, RolBase y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id) &&
                x.Nombre.Equals(y.Nombre);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(RolBase obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Nombre.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
var ResultQuery = (from ES in DbMaster.Estudiantes
                               join I in DbMaster.Inscripciones on ES.strCedula equals I.strCedEstud
                               join C in DbMaster.Carreras on I.strCodCarrera equals C.strCodigo
                               where ES.strCedula.Equals(Cedula)
                               select new RolBase { Id = "EST", Nombre = "Estudiante" }).ToList();
```

**3.**

```
return ResultQuery.Distinct(new RolBaseComparer()).ToList()
```

Comment: Yeah it "works" but you are doing the Distinct on the client-side. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities#set-methods where you can see that the Distinct method that takes an equality comparer is not supported.